# List with several data needs to be converted or used as JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

I've collected some info from a specific api for 2 different nodes but same parameters and having problem to use it in a proper json format and not able to use the key index.
I'm not a professional so appreciate to give me feedback if there is a logical/algorithm mistake or a code mistake.

Thanks in advance.

This the raw data:

```
raw_data = [b'[{"aNodeName": "nodeA","aPortName": "portB"}, {"aNodeName": "nodeC","aPortName": "portD"}]', 
        b'[{"aNodeName": "nodeX","aPortName": "portY"}, {"aNodeName": "nodeZ","aPortName": "portQ"}]' ]
```

I want to change it to a usefull json format, first decode and put each data set to a new list.

```
data_json = []

for w in raw_data:
    data_change = w.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    data_json.append(data_change)
```

Here for every element of a list I made the json format trasnformation:

```
import json

for e in data_json:
    
    don = json.loads(e)
    son = json.dumps(don, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    
    print(son)
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        "aNodeName": "nodeA",
        "aPortName": "portB"
    },
    {
        "aNodeName": "nodeC",
        "aPortName": "portD"
    }
]
[
    {
        "aNodeName": "nodeX",
        "aPortName": "portY"
    },
    {
        "aNodeName": "nodeZ",
        "aPortName": "portQ"
    }
]
```

but I want to use a specific key like `print(son['aNodeName'])`  to get relevant key values and it gives error like below. What am I missing, thanks in advance.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-963acd08e3d7> in <module>
      6     son = json.dumps(don, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
      7 
----> 8     print(son['aNodeName'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You'll likely get some feedback if you specify language you use to write code as a tag. Also re-read [mre] guidance on posting code and review the code in the question in that light (I have no idea if whatever you posted is enough for someone to see the problem, so it very well may be you already provided all required info).

Comment: Also consider reading documentation on "dumps" method - it looks like error says it produces a string rather than an object... So potentially you just using wrong variable and question should be closed as "typo".